# Update a mongoose array

Tags: arrays, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
first_name      : String,
other_names     : String,
last_name       : String,
title           : String,   
friends     :[{
    _id             : String,
    friend_type     : String,//e.g. best, school
    comment         : String,//the school where this email is also linked to
    nickname        : String
}]
```

I have some data in nickname, but the other fields I do not have any information 
I want to update friends array with friend_type which current does not exist in the db. 
These is what I have tried so far.

```
PersonModel.update({
    _id: 'users id is here',
    'friends[0]._id': friend_id,
  }, {
    $set: {
      'friends[0].friend_type': 'office'
    }
  },
  /**
   Other options that I tried arebelow
  **************/
  //{$addToSet: { 'friends[0].friend_type': 'office'} },
  //{$push: { 'friends[0].friend_type': 'office'} },
  {
    multi: true
  },
  function(err, friendDetail) {
  });
```

Please what can i do

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 {$set: { 'friends.0.friend_type': 'office'} }
```

Since you want to not update the main object but its child elements

Comment: i tried that also earlier but it did not work. it was $ sign that worked. thanks